# AngularJS: how to use $http in config phase

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a single page application using angular. We use Continuous Integration with several *Dev* and *QA* environments. This means that every time I deploy the app in a different environment I need to update some config parameters such as SPA baseUrl, rest api url or url for my oauth server.

To achieve this, our CI engine generates a config.json file with the correct parameters for each environment when we are about to deploy there. To get this I have created a really simple service:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('config', config);

  config.$inject = ['$http'];

  function config($http) {
    return {
      load: load
    };

    //////////

    function load() {
      return $http.get('assets/config/config.json');
    }
  }
}());
```

Most of my services are configured through providers during the *config phase*. And here is where the problem comes up. As you know, services cannot be injected during this phase but I would like to use *config* service to set up my providers with the correct URLs and parameters.

Is there a proper way to do this?

The only thing I can consider so far is having these config parameters embed in my module creation file so they are there ready to use. It seems quite ugly since I don´t want any external process to my app modifying my source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are asynchronous services that rely on config.json, it is perfectly ok to change the way they are configured and fit your config into async workflow, e.g.

```
app.factory('config', function ($http) {
  return $http.get('config.json', { cache: true })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    });
});

app.factory('asyncService', function ($http, config) {
  return config.then(function (config) {
    return $http...
  }).then(...);
});
```

Otherwise the best option is to build json config to a service with Gulp/Grunt/whatever.

Think of

```
angular.module('config', []).constant('config', <%= configJson %>);
```

as of a compiled template rather than 'external process to my app modifying my source code'.

Answer (score 1):

What I am doing at the moment (but I am open for a better solution) is to have a separate config file with the json object that contains all the config info.

Example of the file content:

```
var appConfigInfo = {
    DEV: true,
    API_PATH: 'your_custom_url'
    // etc.
};
```

Then I add it as a constant in my app. Example:

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .constant('APP_CONFIG', appConfigInfo);
```

Now you can access all your configuration values via the constant. Don't forget to inject it in your controllers, etc.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I didn´t think about setting them as constants and then using then in my config phase. I will only add that if you set those constants to the *$rootContext* in your run block (such as: `$rootScope.config = config;`), then they are available for every single controller, reducing the number of times you need to inject them into your other components explicitly.

Comment: I haven't considered this option. I'll give it a try :) Thanks!